# IE11 javascript window.outerWidth returns undefined

Tags: javascript, window, hta, outerheight, outerwidth

Google searching says window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight will return the outer dimensions of the current window. However, my HTA file opening in IE11 gives "undefined" for these properties. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Size Test</TITLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    function ShowSize() {
        window.alert("W = " + window.outerWidth+ ", H = " + window.outerHeight);
    }
</SCRIPT>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA"
    applicationName="Size Test"
    border="dialog" 
    borderStyle="normal" 
    caption="yes" 
    innerBorder="no"
    maximizeButton="no" 
    minimizeButton="no" 
    navigable="no"
    scroll="no"
    selection="yes"
    showInTaskbar="yes" 
    singleInstance="yes"
    sysMenu="no"
    windowState="normal"
/>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <button onclick="ShowSize()">test</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The alert dialog shows "W = undefined, H = undefined" (dammit).

Comment: <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />

Comment: Sweet! Thank you so much for a quick response!

Comment: Dang, after adding the meta information, vbscript isn't getting read.

Comment: that's not good! where did you add the meta tag?

Comment: If I put meta before the HTA definition then the javascript window properties work but the window is not formatted correctly and vbscript functions are undefined. If I put the meta after the HTA definition then the window is formatted correctly and vbscript functions are defined, but then the javascript window properties return undefined. (The 4 minute timeout here for edits sucks.)

Comment: I am new to posting at Stack Exchange so I don't know how to post code after the initial post.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Size Test</TITLE>
<META http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />

Comment: That's where I put it (before the HTA definition), and then the javascript window properties work, but the HTA window isn't configured properly and vbscript added to HEAD doesn't get read. So then I moved it to after the HTA definition (but still inside HEAD) and the window is configured properly and vbscript functions are available, but then the javascript window properties are undefined.

Comment: If I move META to between the two SCRIPT tags <HEAD><TITLE>...</TITLE><SCRIPT type="text/vbscript>...</SCRIPT><META...><SCRIPT type="text/javascript>...</SCRIPT><HTA...></HEAD> then the window is formatted correctly, both vbscript and javascript are defined, but now the window properties are undefined again. Grrrrrr (Micros**t....)

Comment: It's just, that HTA is deprecated. The last version with full support was IE9. IE10+ don't support HTA, use "IE=9" as the content of `X-UA`, that will allow you to utilize HTA windows and the most of the features of the newer IEs.